# Find maximum angle of box in slot

Tags: math, trigonometry

How would I find the maximum possible angle (a) which a rectangle of width (W) can be at within a slot of width (w) and depth (h) - see my crude drawing below

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on [math.se].

Comment: @Sam Clay Is answer unclear?

Answer (score 2):

Considering `w = hh + WW` at the picture:

[image]

we can write equation

```
h * tan(a) + W / cos(a) = w
```

Then, using [formulas for half-angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) and `t = tan(a/2)` substitution

```
h * 2 * t / (1 - t^2) + W * (1 + t^2) / (1 - t^2) = w 
h * 2 * t + W * (1 + t^2)  = (1 - t^2) * w 
t^2 * (W + w) + t * (2*h) + (W - w) = 0
```

We have quadratic equation, solve it for unknown `t`,  then get  critical angle as

```
a = 2 * atan(t)
```

Quick check: Python example for picture above gives correct angle value  18.3 degrees

```
import math
h = 2
W = 4.12
w = 5
t = (math.sqrt(h*h-W*W+w*w) - h) / (W + w)
a = math.degrees(2 * math.atan(t))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the above answer as it is not necessarly obvious, this is why why you can write equation:

```
h * tan(a) + W / cos(a) = w
```

[image]

PS: I suppose that the justification for "why `a` is the maximum angle" is obvious